# Sky force reloaded planes

Tags: sky-force-reloaded

So I have all but two planes. The ones I have are:

1. Model 2004.
2. Ambulance.
3. ???
4. Enforcer.
5. Iron clad.
6. Swift justice.
7. Limp berserker.
8. Ace of spades.
9. ???

Anyone have any others and if so how did you get them? Was it random or was it in some level or by doing something specific?

Comment: As of yet, these planes have not been released.